# Create as a polymorphic type in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism

I wish to create a polymorphic class (User) as a particular type and use it later with conditions depending on the type of object.

```
class SuperUser < User
class Admin < User
class User

@user = @account.users.new(params[:user])
```

This will create a user as a User object.  Only way I can think of creating and using @user as a particular type of object is by doing something like this:

```
@user = Admin.new(params[:user]) if params[:user][:type] == "Admin"
@user = SuperUser.new(params[:user]) if params[:user][:type] == "SuperUser"
@user.account = @account

if @user.is_a? Admin 
 ...
end

....
```

So, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `polymorphic_new` class method for User

```
class User
  def self.polymorphic_new(params)
    case params[:type]
    when "Admin" then Admin.new(params)
    when "SuperUser" then SuperUser.new(params)
    else new(params)
  end
end
```

And then in controller

```
@user = User.polymorphic_new(params[:user])
```

I'm not concerned the security question though..

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I'm making one assumption. The `params[:user][:type]` is same as the class name. If thats the case the following code should work.

```
if params[:user][:type]
  @user = (params[:user][:type]).constantize.new(params[:user])
  @user.account = @account
else
  @user = @account.users.new(params[:user]
end
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I think a cleaner solution will be to keep the logic in the model so marked Mik_Die with accepted answer.